# Eclipse: When another file tab is clicked, the window would be split. How to prevent this

Tags: eclipse

[image]

For example, I am here on tab `UnityTest.java`. When I click on `Company.java`, the window is automatically split like:

[image]

This is very annoying. How to prevent this? I hope to view the code just like the tabs in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

**Splitting horizontally :** "Ctrl" + "Shift" + "-" 
**Splitting vertically :** "Ctrl" + "Shift" + "[" 
This is for the Qwerty keyboard. If you're using the Azerty keyboard you should use this : 
**Splitting horizontally :** "Ctrl" + "_"
**Splitting vertically :** "Ctrl" + "{"

If this does not work, go to **Windom > Editor > Toggle Split Editor** and see if it changes.

P.S : If none of the above functionalities work, try to drag the java-File from the Package Explorer on the tab, while holding the split combination.